# prove a polynomial is divisible

Tags: derivatives, polynomials

How do I prove that if a polynomial $p(x)$ is divisible by $(ax+b)^n$ where $n>1$ then $p'(x)$ is divisible by $(ax+b)^{n-1}$

I have no idea how to prove that but by logic it is obvious that is true since the derivate of $p(x)$ lowers the power by 1.

Thank you

Comment: Let $p(x)=(ax+b)^nq(x)$, and compute the derivative.

Comment: Hint: write $p(x)=(ax+b)^nq(x)$ and take the derivative.

Comment: thanks for the answers but what is $q(x)$ ?

Comment: @ben Any polynomial term, doesn't matter

Comment: $q(x)$ is just some other polynomial, you don't need to worry about its exact value.

Comment: great, thanks everyone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**. Write down what in means for $p$ to be a multiple of $(ax+ b)^n$, namely there is some $q$ such that 
$$ p(x) = q(x)(ax+b)^n $$
Now differentiate this equation and see.

Comment: thanks for the answer but what is $q(x)$ ? any random polynom?

Comment: By the definition of being divisible, $p$ is divisible by $(ax+b)^n$, iff there is a polynomial $q$ such that $p(x) = q(x)(ax+b)^n$, this $q$ is called the quotient.